# Passing a db_query as a parameter

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass a db_query as a parameter in a function, but I am not getting what I want.
For example

```
function some_function(){
    $query = "SELECT text FROM my_table";
    $result = db_query( $query );

    $text = other_function( $result );

    echo $text;
}

function other_function( &$result ){
     $array = db_fetch_array( $result );
     return $array['text'];
}
```

I have verified that the query works and that this works if I don't run it through another function. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Any ideas of a better way to do this? I would still like to be able to use a separate function to fetch the arrays from my db_query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

remove the &. It seems unnecessary here. Also, I would use objects for this sort of job, this way you can simply use `$this->result` or its similarities.